# How does one parenthetically amend a noun in a sentence so that both the singular and plural form are included?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, parentheses

In a complex sentence with two subjects, each taking separate actions, the second subject is *item* (singular), which I want to amend to *item(s)* with a parenthetical *s*.

How do I direct the rest of the action? Do I say *was (were)*, or do I just say one of them (either *was* or *were*), or what?

Here's the sentence I'm trying to write:

> Of the women who specified where their favorite item(s) was purchased.

Comment: In all such cases, you rephrase the sentence.

Comment: I would strongly advise avoiding such a thing if at all possible; it’s clumsy and doesn’t look at all good. Try rewording so it isn’t needed.  At worst, say "item or items", but even that is suboptimal.

Answer (score 6):

In your case, you can just use the plural:

> where their favorite items were purchased

since this doesn't necessarily require that each woman have multiple favorite items. (Consider ["their hearts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their+hearts%22), which doesn't require that each person have multiple hearts.)

If it's necessary, for whatever reason, to emphasize that some women might have specified only one favorite item, then you can write out both the singular and plural versions of the subject, conjoined with "or", and use the verb that agrees with the plural version:

> where their favorite item or items were purchased

(By the way, I'm guessing you already realize this, but: your sentence is not a complete sentence. It seems to be just an adverbial.)

Comment: It's the title of a statistical document. Thanks for the help- I'll just say "their favorite items"